# Yii2 cannot reach the backend part

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I really don't get it how can i get to that backend .. How i installed the advanced template is like the way they show it in the official site : `http://www.yiiframework.com/download/` . Everything step by step. When i try frontend.dev (in my case `eshop`) i am redirected to the front end part but when i try backend.dev(in my case `eshop/admin`) i am also redirected to the frontend.
This is my host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#   127.0.0.1       modules
127.0.0.1       eshop
127.0.0.1       eshop/admin

0.0.0.1 mssplus.mcafee.com
```

And the vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eshop
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/frontend/web/"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/frontend/web/">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php

        # use index.php as index file
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        # ...other settings...
        # Apache 2.4
        Require all granted

        ## Apache 2.2
        # Order allow,deny
        # Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eshop/admin
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/backend/web/"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/backend/web/">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php

        # use index.php as index file
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        # ...other settings...
        # Apache 2.4
        Require all granted

        ## Apache 2.2
        # Order allow,deny
        # Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where is my mistake ? A lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: Yii2 Advance Template [Installing Using Composer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md).

Comment: Propably `eshop/admin` is recognized as `eshop` frontend and `admin` as controller. Try to set vhost as `admin.eshop` or something.

Comment: Yes, it work if the separator is a dot ( . ) but what is the right way to make it a slash ( / ) ? Should I add some changes to the `.htaccess` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a slash (/) in hostname is illegal, as it is defined in [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952). Therefore in the URL "http://eshop/admin" the server name is "eshop" and apache is using of course your first virtual server setting.
Summarized, your idea will never work. You should use eshop-admin as server name.